# Delay while opening new activity first time

Tags: android, xamarin, android-activity, xamarin.android

I am working on a Xamarin Android project. I have some animations in Splash (first) screen. After ending all animations I am starting an Activity. So the problem is that first time it takes 2-3 seconds to navigate on next Activity. After that it takes only one second to navigate on that Activity unless I clear the recent applications list. After clearing it again takes 2-3 seconds.

Please suggest what is wrong here and how can it be fixed.

**Splash Activity**

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true,NoHistory = true, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class SplashScreenActivity : Activity
{
    private ImageView CircleImage;
    private ImageView SquakrLogo;

    private TextView text;
    private RelativeLayout logoRelativeLayout;

    Animation CircleImageAnimation;
    Animation SquakrLogoAnimation;
    Animation LargeDotAnimation;
    Animation PluseAnimation;

    Intent intentObject;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SplashScreen);
        logoRelativeLayout = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.logo_layout);
        CircleImage = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.circle_image_view);
        SquakrLogo = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.logo_image_view);
        text = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text);

        CircleImageAnimation = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this, Resource.Animation.SplashTVAnimation);
        SquakrLogoAnimation = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this, Resource.Animation.SplashLogoAnimation);
        LargeDotAnimation = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this, Resource.Animation.SplashLastAnimation);
        PluseAnimation = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this, Resource.Animation.SplashPulseAnimation);

        intentObject = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));

    }

    public override void OnWindowFocusChanged(bool hasFocus)
    {
        base.OnWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if(hasFocus)
        {
            CircleImage.StartAnimation(CircleImageAnimation);
            CircleImageAnimation.AnimationEnd += CircleImageAnimation_AnimationEnd; 
        }
    }


    private void CircleImageAnimation_AnimationEnd(object sender, Animation.AnimationEndEventArgs e)
    {
        SquakrLogo.StartAnimation(SquakrLogoAnimation);
        CircleImage.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
        logoRelativeLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        SquakrLogoAnimation.AnimationStart += SquakrPluseAnimation_AnimationStart;
        SquakrLogoAnimation.AnimationEnd += SquakrPluseAnimation_AnimationEnd;
    }

    private void SquakrPluseAnimation_AnimationStart(object sender, Animation.AnimationStartEventArgs e)
    {
        global::Android.Widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
        param.AddRule(LayoutRules.CenterInParent);
        CircleImage.LayoutParameters = param;
        CircleImage.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    }

    private void SquakrPluseAnimation_AnimationEnd(object sender, Animation.AnimationEndEventArgs e)
    {
        CircleImage.StartAnimation(PluseAnimation);
        PluseAnimation.AnimationEnd += SquakrLogoAnimation_AnimationEnd;
    }


    private void SquakrLogoAnimation_AnimationEnd(object sender, Animation.AnimationEndEventArgs e)
    {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
        param.AddRule(LayoutRules.CenterInParent);
        CircleImage.LayoutParameters = param;
        CircleImage.ScaleX = 2.0f;
        CircleImage.ScaleY = 2.0f;
        CircleImage.StartAnimation(LargeDotAnimation);
        LargeDotAnimation.AnimationStart += delegate
          {
            logoRelativeLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
          };
        LargeDotAnimation.AnimationEnd += Last_AnimationEnd;
    }

    private void Last_AnimationEnd(object sender, Animation.AnimationEndEventArgs e)
    {
        StartActivity(intentObject);
        Finish();
    }
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
 #region Methods
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initTodaysLineUp();
        GetSavedToken();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(refreshToken))
        {
            GetUserPreferences();
        }

        //PackageInfo info = this.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo("co.Squawkr", PackageInfoFlags.Signatures);

        //foreach (Android.Content.PM.Signature signature in info.Signatures)
        //{
        //    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.GetInstance("SHA");
        //    md.Update(signature.ToByteArray());

        //    string keyhash = Convert.ToBase64String(md.Digest());
        //}
        if(SquawkrLoginManager.getInstance().isLoggedIn()){
            UserInfo userInfo = SquawkrLoginManager.getInstance().GetLastLoggedInUser();
            UpdatePushBadgeCount(userInfo);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SquawkrLoginManager.getInstance().getDeviceId()) && !SquawkrLoginManager.getInstance().sendDeviceIdToServer())
            {
                SquawkrLoginManager.getInstance().SendNotificationRegistrationToServer(this);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe OnWindowFocusChanged is called multiple times at first start?

Comment: You are showing the the splash screen activity, not the MainActivity, that is were your processing to create and show it exists. (Also personally I drop the splash screen activity, all your doing here is consuming cpu and memory and slowing down the startup, it you really need a "splash screen", consider a theme-based one attached to your MainActivity.

Comment: @Frank Thank you for replying. I just added `OnWindowFocusChanged`. Before this I was doing this work in `OnCreate`.

Comment: @SushiHangover Thank you for reply. I am calling an API in `OnCreate` and saving some data to shared preference. Please tell me what do you mean by this "consider a theme-based one attached to your MainActivity"

Comment: @AshishTiwari In the `OnCreate` that you posted, there are only FindViewByID and LoadAnimation calls, I do not see any shared preference   references.

Comment: @SushiHangover I just updated my question, provided Main Activity's OnCreate

Comment: @SushiHangover I have commented all the code that is calling the APIs and saving data, but still its taking time.

Comment: @AshishTiwari You would need to profile the app to determine what areas are consuming the time, is it the layout complexity, the widgets in the layout, the time to load of the assemblies into memory, the Java VM Jit'ing, and Mono Jit'ing, loading resources, the I/O speed of the flash/drive system, CPU speed, etc...